# Magento Pagination URL issues

Tags: php, magento, pagination

I am having an issue. i don't know if it's being caused by my custom template or what...

But say I am on a page like so
/incense-oils/incense-incense-burners-and-charcoal.html

Then I see the pagination numbers 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 etc.

I click 2 and it takes me to 
/incense-oils/incense-incense-burners-and-charcoal.html?p=2

ONce I am on the 2nd page (doesn't have to be page 2 just once i click the pagination ONCE)

Now when I hover over the 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 the links have become like so

/incense-oils/incense-incense-burners-and-charcoal.html&p=3

So they are adding an ampersand & instead of a ? question mark and therefore it causes the page to just hang, but in reality it's throwing a 404 in chrome developer tools.  Just not sure where to even look to fix this or if there's some regular expression I can write to replace the & with a ? if there is no ?.

I didn't update pagination at all or install any module for it. Anyone have any idea why it's doing this or where i can look into the code to fix it?

Comment: Work backwards to debug.  Remove your custom theme, remove all custom extensions.  This doesn't occur with stock Magento, so work backwards towards stock Magento until the problem is fixed.  Then you can narrow down the root cause.

Comment: Well I know it's coming from the custom theme.  SO just trying to get an idea of where to start.

Comment: Again, it starts with basic debugging.  If you know it's related to your theme, then remove/rename theme files and folder until the issue stops occurring. Then narrow down to the exact file, exact line of code.  It's simply the process of elimination that will tell you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Yes I am fully aware how to debug. However I am NOT a php developer so it's not that simple. While I have looked at the pager functionality that is built in I can't for the life of me figure out what's causing it. Which is why I decided to post here. I can't find the exact line of code.  Figured if someone out there was actually familiar with Magento they may be able to point me in the right direction.

Comment: I just did point you in the right direction.  RENAME the files and folder in your theme until the issue stops occurring.  Once you find the folder that the issue is in, then move to the files and rename those one-by-one.  You don't need to know PHP to determine where the cause of the issue is.

Comment: The problem is it will remove the pagination completely that doesn't stop the issue it just removes it from the page. There are 5+ files that make the pagination work so just because I rename one and it stops working doesn't mean that's the file or line of code in question. I've already gone through all the files I have it narrowed down to a few, doesn't mean i know what to do to fix it.

Comment: Ok pretty sure i found the code however it's too long to post as a comment. Ok so the links are obviously being built in this block of code but ultimately ALL the links on this page are done the same way so i guess i don't need to post it all... <a class="next_jump" title="" href="<?php echo $this->getNextJumpUrl() ?>">...</a> 
So this for instance creates a bad link.  My guess is the problem has to do with the $this portion of it?  vs the function it's calling since no matter what function is used it seems to create it incorrectly.  Hope that even makes sense.

Comment: The files should be just overrides of the default Magento base template, so renaming them the pagination should "fall-back" and go back to default pagination.  If not, then there might be some customization in the theme that changes the default pagination behavior (which there shouldn't be).  If renaming the files removes the pagination completely then one of the XML files in the theme's layouts folder might be changing the template name for the pagination.

Comment: Yeah i see that now, sorry I wasn't aware thats how it worked.

Comment: Ok well i found the file and disabled it. Still no idea what is causing it in that actual file.  But at lesat I have a working site now.